# CmakeLists.txt - Change Source path - failed finding Header file

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using OpenCV code and added some code of mine.
I'm very new in this topic so be patient with me.

I've changed a file in the source code, but would prefer instead of saving and ruining the original file, to save it on separate folder and just changed the CMakeFile in order to use it.

My problem is when I've changed the src code path of a file in the CMakeLists.txt to my file located outside of the main folder.

- MyCode

  - Moudles

    - loadsave.cpp
- OpenCvCode

  - Moudles

    - loadsave.cpp

After running the CMake and compiling the project in Visual Studio everything works fine. I can see **MY** file being used in the solution and it passes compilation.

When i run it in my docker - Compilation fails and says that he can't find the first header file included in this file.

loadsave.cpp is not my file. I've only added some code there.

```
#22 441.9 [ 93%] Building CXX object modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/opencv_sources/my_code/module/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp.o
#22 441.9 /opencv_sources/my_code/module/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:46:23: fatal error: precomp.hpp: No such file or directory
#22 441.9  #include "precomp.hpp"
#22 441.9                        ^
#22 441.9 compilation terminated.
```

Original CMake File was

```
set(imgcodecs_srcs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/loadsave.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/utils.cpp
    )
```

I've changed it to

```
set(MY_RELATIVE_FOLDER "../../../../my_code/module/imgcodecs")
set(imgcodecs_srcs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${MY_RELATIVE_FOLDER}/src/loadsave.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/utils.cpp
    )
```

Comment: You probably need to use target_include_directories() to add an additional include directory when compiling `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${MY_RELATIVE_FOLDER}/src/loadsave.cpp` so it finds the `precomp.hpp` file which appears to be in a different folder than the loadsave.cpp

Comment: Apparently What I've tried in the morning `include_directories()` did the job already - but I was all day fighting with it just because `--no-cache` in Docker did not copied the updated CMakeLists (Wierd). But thank you for the comment.. It is just made me more focus on the files in the container itself (Docker) !!

Comment: OpenCV is available as git repository and even if you work outside of this repo, you could still create a local git repo for your source code. This would allow pretty easily go back to an old state. If you create a folder structure that does not match the final folder structure, you're just creating more work for yourself in the future...

Comment: You are right... But our project contain so many 3rd parties that we customized (such as Open Jpeg, GDal, OpenCV...) with so many files that we simply compress each library to `tar.gz` and creating batch file to create a window development environment when seldom one need to develop it. It is like that designed so it will be less heavy on our Git and as well pass good with the Docker images.